# How to access View Controller from Tab bar controller?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uinavigationcontroller

I have a tab bar controller and each tab consist of a navigation controller.

How can I access a specific view controller in a navigation controller in a tab so that I can access a property specific to the view controller?

I tried the following code:

```
//Get the navigation controller of the 3rd tab
self.tabController.selectedViewController 
= [self.tabController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:2];

//Attempt to retrieve the viewcontroller I want from the tabcontroller
SomeViewController *svc = (SomeViewController *)self.tabController.selectedViewController;

//Attempting to access a BOOLEAN property in svc viewcontroller
svc.someProperty = YES;
```

The above code failed because it seems that "self.tabController.selectedViewController" returns me a navigation controller. How can I extend the code so that I can access "svc.someProperty"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`-topViewController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UINavigationController/topViewController) to get the view controller from the navigation controller (or [`-visibleViewController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UINavigationController/visibleViewController) if you are using modal view controllers).

Answer (score 4):

If `self.tabController.selectedViewController` is your navigation view controller, then you can access the currently visible controller using:

[`visibleViewController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UINavigationController/visibleViewController)

and the top view controller using:

[`topViewController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UINavigationController/topViewController)

If this does not allow you to get to `SomeViewController`, you can iterate through the list of controllers pushed on the navigation controller stack:

[`viewControllers`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UINavigationController/viewControllers)

Comment: sergio, I've used your answer, but I get `0x0` for all those values, even though I'm looking at the selectedViewController.  [What could be causing it?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7433189/266252)

Answer (score 1):

Since the view controller is a subview of the returned UINavigationController(SVC), you could just send it the following method `[svc topViewController];`.  That should return you the view controller and then you should be able to access the property.