# ViewController Hierarchy getting 'lost'

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller

I've got a view hierarchy which is setup (programmatically) as follows:

Window.root = TabBarController-->UINavigationControllers-->UIViewControllers

I presume that's rather standard. Here's my problem:

I'm on Tab A. I want to navigate to Tab B, and call a method on the visibleViewController on Tab B.

```
// View Changes OK
[AppDelegate.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:tabB];

// nav  = 0x387ABF i.e. Valid Address
UINavigationController *nav = (UINavigationController*)[AppDelegate.tabBarController selectedViewController];

// The problem:
nav.viewControllers; // this is nil
nav.topViewController; // as is this
nav.visibleViewContorller; // this too.
```

Even if I put the calls to `nav.viewControllers` in a separate method which is called from the Main Thread, I still get `0x0`/`nil`.

What am I doing wrong?

A follow-up question is:
How can I pass information from one ViewController to another when changing tabs?  (If I can't call methods on VC's from tabA to tabB)

[I have a feeling it is related to my question here.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7112085/266252)

Comment: in the debugger console, the nav object will have some components in a drop down form...check if they have nil(0x0) value too. If yes, then your navigation controllers have not been properly initialised

Comment: @tipycalFlow I create the nav controller with `[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc];` - how else am I supposed to initialize it?

Comment: @tipycalFlow, the only values that are 0x0 are _delegate, _disappearingViewController, and _toolbar.  I'm not using a toolbar, don't think I have to set the delegate, and I'm not in the middle of animation, so _disappearingViewController I presume is OK as 0x0.

Comment: OK...first of all, take it easy man...it's not a freakin competition. I was only trying to help!!! Second, does it have a `viewControllers` property?

Comment: @tipycalFlow the navigationController should have a .viewControllers property... right?  It returns 0x0 when I access it, even though it returns a proper array right after I init it.  It seems to "lose" the value after the tab it is on gets displayed for the first time.

Comment: This is weird...(just to check) did you create a navigation controller for every tab?

Comment: I mean like `tabBarController.viewControllers = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:firstNavController, secondNavController,...., nil];`

Comment: yup.  gotta wait 1 more day though.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3523/discussion-between-stephen-furlani-and-tipycalflow)

Answer (score 0):

You should store the information in a common place, either a singleton or as you are a beginner just make a class and pass it down.

```
sharedDataObject = [[MySharedDataObject alloc] init];

firstViewController.myDataObject = sharedDataObject;
secondViewController.myDataObject = sharedDataObject;
```

Comment: My problem is that secondViewController is returning nil.  I can't set the properties of an object that I can't access.

Comment: To be clear, i was suggesting adding this code at the time you create both the view controllers and add them to the tab bar, in each one you then have a shared data store you can do things with.